# Consuming Rest API with .Net HttpClient fails Authorization when Access Token is not gotten directly

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-1.0

The server is a .net core API that uses Identity for authentication/authorization and [SimpleTokenProvider](https://github.com/nbarbettini/SimpleTokenProvider) for generating the JWT tokens. The particular endpoint requires a role authorization.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

When I get a token from a different controller action method, saves the token in a session and tries to use that token to call the API, or when I hard-code a token gotten from Postman and passes it to the API, the user gets authenticated on the server, but fails to authorize.

The only way the user gets authorized is if I request for the token inside the same controller action method. It also works fine from Postman.

The client code is as below:

```
    string token = "ew0KICAiYWxnIjogIkhTMjU2IiwNCiAg...";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));    
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5001/api/dashboard").Result;
          if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
             Console.Write(httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
          }
```

From the server logs, the authorized calls for the same endpoint has the following:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5001/api/dashboard     
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Identity.Application.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: Successfully validated the token.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Bearer.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization was successful for user: xxxxx.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization was successful for user: xxxxx.
```

While the unauthorized calls has the following logs:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5001/api/dashboard  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: Successfully validated the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Bearer.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization was successful for user: xxxxx.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed for user: xxxxx.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
```

I don't know what other option needs to be added to HttpClient for the authorizations to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using wireshark to trace the difference in the requests from HttpClient and Postman, i discovered that .Net Identity sets a Cookie named .AspNetCore.Identity.Application after a user signs in which must be sent as part of the requests for the authorization to work.

After getting the cookie and setting it as part of the subsequent requests, it works fine.

[image: Wireshark screenshot]